# How do I combine Image URIs into a gif in js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, uri, gif

So I've been searching around the internet and nobody seems to have the answers I need so I have come here to ask how would I go about making a gif creator in pure js, no libraries or jquery or npm. I've found some code that can take canvas data and turn it into a URI and download it but I can't seem to find a way to piece URIs together to make a gif. I think it's possible with all the image + image to gif, gif to URI, and image to URI generators out there. And here is the code I've got so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Pixel Art Creator</h2>
<Title>Pixel Art Creator</Title>
<p id="txt"></p>
<canvas id="download_canvas" width="10" height="10"></canvas><br>  
<button onclick="downloadCanvas()">Download Me!</button>
<button onclick="getURL()">Get URL</button><br>
<p>Size</p><input type="range" min="1" max="200" value="10" id="size">
<script>


var sizeslider = document.getElementById("size");
var canvas = document.getElementById( 'download_canvas' );  
  
window.onload = function(){  
    init();  
};  
  




sizeslider.oninput = function() {
canvas.width=canvas.height=this.value
init();
}


function init(){  
    var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );  
  
    context.beginPath();  
  
    // draw a blue rectangle 
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';  
    context.fillRect( 0, 0, 150, 100 );  
  
    // draw a red rectangle 
    context.fillStyle = 'red';  
    context.fillRect( 60, 50, 150, 100 );  
}






function downloadCanvas(){  
    // get canvas data  
//    var image = canvas.toDataURL();  
  
    // create temporary link  
//    var tmpLink = document.createElement( 'a' );  
//    tmpLink.download = 'image.gif'; // set the name of the download file 
//    tmpLink.href = image; 
//    tmpLink.href = canvas.toDataURL();
  
    // temporarily add link to body and initiate the download  
//    document.body.appendChild( tmpLink );  
//    tmpLink.click();  
//    document.body.removeChild( tmpLink );  




    var tmpLink = document.createElement( 'a' );  
    tmpLink.download = 'image.gif'; // set the name of the download file 
    tmpLink.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    tmpLink.click();  


}


function getURL() {

    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = canvas.toDataURL();

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So can anyone help me with these three things?

1. find where that code is originally from
2. tell me how to combine URIs or just the images together
3. point me to the right place to help me with learning it all together.

I'm not the best at js, I understand a decent portion of it but there is a lot I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I found CCapture.js but that didn't work so I found jsgif on git hub if anyone else has the same problem, the link is https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif.